# Programmatically set start_datetime for recurring profiles

Tags: recurring

I want to set start_datetime for a recurring profile programmatically to the first day of the next year. how can i archieve this? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's say, you have loaded the recurring profile in `$profile`, for example with

```
$profile = Mage::getModel('sales/recurring_profile')->load($profileId);
```

Then you can set the date like this:

```
$profile->setStartDatetime($startDate)->save()
```

where `$startDate` must be a string in Magentos standard format. To set it to the first day of next year, you can use:

```
$startDate = Varien_Date::formatDate(
    'next year Jan 01', Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
$profile->setStartDatetime($startDate)->save()
```